# Are new mathematics required to solve problems on the frontier of contemporary physics?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, physics, mathematical-physics, philosophy

I would like to ask about the following question, and I hope that is suitable. We know that there are relationships between mathematics and mathematical physics, let's say that in physics are used mathematics in the theories of professors that are studying the cosmos.

Currently there are unsolved problems in physics, great problems, for example Wikipedia has the article *List of unsolved problems in physics* where I recognize some of the most popularized of those unsolved problems. I know about the most famous from an informative point of view.

And I could be right if I think that some of these problems are not (to this date) accessible or attackable because there no exist suitable mathematical tools/techniques to solve or to get a good resollution for these problems. Maybe this thought is naive, I'm asking it from the ignorance.

> **Question.** Are there clear clues that this is the real situation? I mean with (the purpose to clarify) this question that maybe there are clues that support the idea that are required new mathematical methods/ideas to attack these problems. **Many thanks.**

I would like to know if this can be a good post and if this question is answerable. I'm asking this as a soft question, I don't know if it corresponds to some philosophical point of view. If there are useful references from the literature then refer the literature answering my question as a reference request and I try to search and read those ideas about what clues telling us that for solving some of the problems in the frontier of the contemporary physics will be required new mathematics.

If you think that there is not such relationship, and that there are enough mathematical theories to solve many of those unsolved problems in physics, explain it as an answer.

Since there are several important/popularized unsolved problems in physics, I'm asking just an illustration for some of those in your discussion.

Comment: If this isn't a suitable post, please feel free to add you feedback in comments. It is appreciated.

Comment: Would you like to give some examples of those problems unsolvable under the current mathematics framework?

Comment: I'm asking from the ignorance, if I'm right there are unsolved problems in physics, and with the word *cosmos* I understand the *everything*. I can't add more details, I'm asking if there are clues indicating that we need new mathematics for some unsolved problems in physics. I don't know if my question is in the literature or it is just an  interpretation of mine. Many thanks @user12986714

Comment: What I can to provide is my interpretation that what happens in the past (problems in physics for which were required new mathematics of contemporary professors or mathematical physicists to solve it), always from my limited knowledges @user12986714 . But I am asking about the current problems in the frontier of physics. Many thanks for your attention again.

Comment: We already know that new math or new physics (read: implementation of math) is necessary just with quantum field theory alone. There are some pretty serious gaps there that need addressing. Either we need to develop some deeper math or adjust the theory to address these gaps.

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution @CameronWilliams , feel free to add an answer with your discussion.

Comment: If I understand well, only the study of the Solar System motivated Newton's theory of gravitation (analysis and Euclidean geometry in the study of movement of the Moon and other celestial object). After if I'm right Einstein used Riemannian geometry in the formulation of his general theory of relativity. And at this date it seems that we can't elucidate how is our Solar System. I have not mentioned other examples that I know (using matrix theory or functional analysis). I think that the post was as an opportunity to bring here an interesting question, any case many thanks @CameronWilliams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, new mathematics are required. Just as Newton had to invent calculus in order to express his physics more elegantly; so, too, do physicists today have to generalize their mathematics in order to account for new experimental and observational results.

The need for a new mathematics such as [Lie-admissible algebras](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Lie-admissible_algebra) for physics is motivated at a high, philosophical level in:

- Santilli, Ruggero Maria. “[An Introduction to New Sciences for a New Era](http://www.santilli-foundation.org/docs/new-sciences-new-era.pdf).” [*Clifford Analysis, Clifford Algebras, and Their Applications*](http://www.cliffordanalysis.com/) 6, no. 1 (2017): 1–119.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I've known in the past, as graduated student, that Lie groups and Lie algebras have applications to physics. My current knowledges aren't the best, but I am going to try to understand the definition that you refer. Many thanks again, sure that your post is also interesting for other users.